# What Asp.net Mvc facility should I use to automatically convert ticks into DateTime when passing to a Controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, datetime, model-binding

I want my api to have pretty urls

```
/controller/action/param1/param2...
```

What I'd like is something like

```
 public ActionResult Index([ConvertFromTicks]DateTime birthdate, string meal)
        {
```

Or perhaps even a global ActionFilter... whatever's best practice. My problem is, *the routing mechanism doesn't even see the controller* unless a valid DateTime is passed to it. This makes routing pretty URLs with DateTime parameters impossible. Other Answers on similar questions suggest passing in the date as the number of milliseconds since the epoch, or some other url-friendly format, and converting it in the controller. I don't want to have to do this for every controller that uses a DateTime parameter (almost all 60 them). I also don't want the next developer to maintain this solution to have to remember to invoke the magic words, or get a confusing 404, DateTime.Parse exception or inconsistent results.

What are my options here?

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing how you want your URL to look like, if the intent is to have URL human readable and flexible then maybe syntax such as http://service/action?date=YYYY-MM-DDTHHMMSS or date="some string" would give you most flexibility and have a static helper method to parse various strings.

As you seem to have a large number of controllers, I would opt for Action Filter to keep the code clean.

Comment: added pretty url requirement above